# error checking push permissions in gitlap cicd pipeline

Tags: gitlab, cicd

error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: getting tag for destination: repository can only contain the characters `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-./`:

when i try to build using gitlab cicd pipe line i am facing error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: getting tag for destination: repository can only contain the characters `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-./`: